# Meaning of quote by Goedel

Tags: philosophy-of-language, free-will, goedel

"The meaning of the world is the separation of wish and fact. Wish is a force as applied to thinking beings, to realize something. A fulfilled wish is a union of wish and fact. The meaning of the whole world is the separation and the union of fact and wish". [9.4.3]

Why does he say that "*A fulfilled wish is a **union** of wish and fact* ?. And in *"The meaning of the whole world is the separation and the union of fact and wish"*, why is World the separation and the union of fact and wish, and not simply "an altered fact, say **F'** "? Why *fulfilment of wish* does not change the "fact **F** of the World"? Why is Godel observing *and* maintaining distinction between the facts of World, and our wishes?

This also raises, what *are* wishes?

Source : Hao Wang’s supplemental biography of Gödel, A Logical Journey, MIT Press, 1996.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wish is a desire for a certain state of affairs.

The "union of wish and fact" he is referring to, is the combination of the wish (the desire for a certain state of affairs) and the fact (the state of affairs that was desired). When both things are present, you have a fulfilled wish: the desire in your mind, combined with what you got to satisfy that desire.

When he says, "the meaning of the whole world is the separation and the union of fact and wish," he is saying that meaning derives from what people desire, and whether or not they get what they desire. For example, he might say the meaning of a wrench is what the wrench can be used for - i.e., which desires the wrench can help in fulfilling.